# Upgrade error: magento 2.1.3 to version 2.2.1

Tags: upgrade, magento-2.1.3, magento2.2

I have **`Upgraded`** **Magento 2.1.3** to **version 2.2.1** then it's giving me an error as follows:

> Exception #0 (InvalidArgumentException): Merge for content type '' is
>   not supported

Please help me anyone solution for that.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Were CSS and JS files merged before you started upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

> set deploy mode developer using **php bin/magento deploy:mode:set developer**
>
> then run **php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy**

Comment: I have tried it, can not work your solution. please let me know any another solution. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. You can see my code for default_head_blocks.xml inside app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/Magento_Theme/layout

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/> 
    <css src="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.css" />
    <css src="css/bootstrap/theme.css" />

    <css src="owl.carousel/assets/owl.carousel.css" />
    <css src="externallink/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/>

    <css src="external-link-to-some-css/css"/>
    <css src="another-external-link-to-some-css/css?family=Delius+Unicase:400,700"/>
    <css src="css/custom.css" />

    <css src="css/flag-icon.css"/>
</head>
```

Then I added src_type="url" at end of every src that was an external link like this example here:

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/> 
    <css src="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.css" />
    <css src="css/bootstrap/theme.css" />

    <css src="owl.carousel/assets/owl.carousel.css" />
    <css src="externallink/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" src_type="url"/> (Here I added src_type=url)

    <css src="external-link-to-some-css/css?:300,400,600,700,800" src_type="url"/> (same here)
    <css src="another-external-link-to-some-css?" src_type="url"/> (same here)
    <css src="css/custom.css" /> 

    <css src="css/flag-icon.css"/>
</head>
```

So, you have to find out which XML is missing something similar like the src-type. We can't see your code for obvious reason, there are so many XML files in a Magento store that we can't point out which is the problem, but I hope the solution for my problem can help yours.